# How to write a function to add edges or vertex to a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to add either a vertex or an edge to a graph, and also sometimes, vertices or edges, or a mixture of the two. How to write a function for this?

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** *Can I add a mixture list of vertices and edges to an existing graph?*

```
ClearAll[addToGraph]
addToGraph[g_Graph, stuffToAdd_] := Fold[
 If[Head[#2] === UndirectedEdge || Head[#2] === DirectedEdge, EdgeAdd, VertexAdd]@ ## &,
 g, stuffToAdd]
```

Example:

```
g = Graph[{a, b, c}, {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Scaled[.1], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 18, AspectRatio -> 1];

addToGraph[g, {d, d <-> a, e, h <-> a}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

The functions you need are `VertexAdd`, `EdgeAdd`, and their relatives `VertexDelete` and `EdgeDelete`.

For the graph

```
g = Graph[{a, b, c}, {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> a}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Scaled[.1], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 18, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Adding a vertex

```
VertexAdd[g, d]
```

[image]

Adding an edge

```
EdgeAdd[g, d <-> a]
```

[image]

Deleting an edge

```
EdgeDelete[g, c <-> a]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I add a mixture list of vertices and edges to an existing graph? How to write such a function `addToGraph[g, {4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}]` which will add another vertex `4` and an edge between `1` and `2`? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in function that does that. But, it seems straightforward to do define a composite function that does both: `addToGraph[g_, newvertices_List, newedges_List]:= (VertexAdd[g,newvertices];EdgeAdd[g,newedges];)`. Use it as `h=addToGraph[g,{d,e},{a->d,a->e}]` to add two new vertices and two new edges to graph `g` to get a new graph `h`.

Comment: I guess I wanted to know what if I mixed the `newvertices_List` and `newedges_List` in a single list?

Comment: @QiangLi, you need modify slightly to parse the new stuff into vertex and edge parts. For example, let `newstuff = {a, a \[UndirectedEdge] b, b \[UndirectedEdge] e, d, b}`. Then, you can use `newedges=Cases[newstuff, _ \[UndirectedEdge] _]; newvertices = Complement[newstuff, newedges]` as the first two steps of the composite function on the right hand side. That is, the function becomes `addToGraph2[g_, newstuff_]:=(newedges=Cases[newstuff, _ \ [UndirectedEdge] _]; newvertices = Complement[newstuff, newedges]; VertexAdd[g,newvertices];EdgeAdd[g,newedges];).

Comment: @QiangLi, you could create a new `Graph` with the new vertices and edges, and then use `GraphUnion`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot for this answer! I was wondering if you wanna have a look at a very similar [question to mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250427/arbitrary-lattice-graph-in-2d?). Your insight can be extremely fruitful to me. Billion thanks in advance!!

Comment: @kglr I tried to follow your route, but I am pretty sure [I am making some mistakes](https://imgur.com/agHsgeb).

Comment: @Shamina, replace `{d, d <-> a, e, h <-> a}` with `{d, d \[UndirectedEdge] a, e, h \[UndirectedEdge] a}`

Comment: It worked, many thanks! Perhaps, your insight would still be very useful to my question ;)