# Arbitrary lattice graph in 2D

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, code-request, lattices

My purpose is to generate a graph representing a lattice, where the vertices are essentially the lattice sites. This lattice has to be periodic. That means the opposite boundaries are identical.
MWE for a square lattice:

```
nx = 5;
ny = 5;
DistributeDefinitions[nx, ny];
mat = (# + Transpose[#]) &[
    ArrayFlatten[
     ParallelTable[
      KroneckerDelta[Mod[xi + 1, nx, 1], xj] KroneckerDelta[yi, yj] + 
       KroneckerDelta[Mod[yi + 1, ny, 1], yj] KroneckerDelta[xi, 
         xj], {xi, nx}, {xj, nx}, {yi, ny}, {yj, ny}]]];
```

This essentially generates a periodic square lattice.
Now we can put a lattice site between two adjacent sites at one of the edges, which is shown in the below graph. To illustrate, there is `3` between `1` and `2`, which was previously missing in the square lattice.
[image]
One can change this number from one to two, as shown below.
[image]
Actually, this number can change, which I refer to as arbitrary (in the heading). Is there a single piece of code that can generate all of these kinds of lattices? Unfortunately, I have to write a single piece of code for each of them. Importantly, there are periodic boundaries shown with red along the $y$-axis and black along the $. x$-axis

***NEW EDIT:***
After useful comments from @flinty, @David and @kglr. My update MWE:

```
ClearAll[nx, ny, mat, gph, nv, edgeA, i, j, nv, edgeA];
{nx, ny} = {4, 4};
mat = AdjacencyMatrix[ResourceFunction["TorusGraph"][{nx, ny}]];
gph = AdjacencyGraph[mat, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

nv[g_, v_, k_] := VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, v]][[k]];
edgeA[m_, g_, v_, k_] := 
  EdgeAdd[
   g, {nv[g, v, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] Length[m] + 2 k + v^2 - 1, 
    Length[m] + 2 k + v^2 - 1 \[UndirectedEdge] nv[g, v, k + 1]}];
vertexA[m_, g_, v_, k_] := 
  EdgeDelete[
   edgeA[m, g, v, k], {nv[g, v, 1] \[UndirectedEdge] nv[g, v, k + 1]}];
checkA[m_, g_, v_, k_] := 
  If[(v < Length[VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, 1]]] - 1 \[And] 
      v == k) \[Or] (nv[g, v, 1] < nv[g, v, k + 1]), 
   vertexA[m, g, v, k], Nothing];

DistributeDefinitions[mat, gph, checkA, nv, edgeA];

ParallelTable[
 checkA[mat, gph, i, j], {i, 1, Length[mat] - 1}, {j, 1, 
  Length[VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[gph, 1]]] - 1}]
```

This actually generates a graph that has added vertex between each pair of adjacent vertices. However, this only generates a different graph, the idea is to update the original graph, and to equip it with these changes. Can we do this?

Comment: Perhaps a double periodic lattice might be represented as a `TorusGraph` since both sides wrap around? e.g `ResourceFunction["TorusGraph"][{10, 4}]`

Comment: @flinty This might work for square type tilling but can we also do it for the one I showed in my questions by tweaking some parameters maybe?

Comment: I would start with @flinty's TorusGraph solution and then use AddEdge (in an iterated loop) to add edges along one of the component graph (circular) paths.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Perfect! Exactly what I want to do. I was using the `EdgeAdd` but I can only an isolated point not connected to any vertices. However, let me still try if I can do something meaningful. Meanwhile, any super short examples are more than welcome ;)

Comment: Step by step:  `g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3},
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]`, `EdgeDelete[g, 1 <-> 2]`,`h = VertexAdd[g, 4]`,`k = EdgeAdd[h, {1 <-> 4, 4 <-> 2}]`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidG.Stork! I am trying to exploit it for the present code.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I updated my question with your inputs, but I think I am not able to update the original graph.

Comment: an aside: you can use `Prepend[v]@AdjacencyList[g, v]` instead of  `VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, v]]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks for this! Is it faster or something?

Comment: It is more direct and faster (especially for large graphs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can add a second argument to `TorusGraph` to specify the number of segments between nodes with integer coordinates in each dimension:

```
ClearAll[torusGraph]
torusGraph[dims : {__Integer}, segs: {__Integer} : {1, 1}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := Module[{m = Length[dims], tg}, 
  tg = Graph[Flatten[Array[Table[Rule @@@ 
     Partition[Function[x, Mod[{##} + UnitVector[m, i] x, dims, 1]] /@ 
           Subdivide[segs[[i]]], 2, 1], {i, m}] &, dims, 1]], opts, 
    DirectedEdges -> False]; 
  IndexGraph @ Graph[Sort@VertexList[tg], EdgeList[tg], 
    VertexCoordinates -> ScalingTransform[{1, -1}][
      RotationTransform[-Pi/2] @ Sort @ VertexList[tg]], opts, 
    VertexLabels -> "Index", EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]]
```

***Examples:***

Default number of segments between original sites is 1:

```
torusGraph[{4, 5}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Add a node in the middle of horizontal edges:

```
torusGraph[{4, 5}, {1, 2}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Add two nodes on horizontal and 1 node on vertical edges:

```
g0 = torusGraph[{4, 5}, {2, 3}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Highlight the added vertices:

```
HighlightGraph[g0, 
 VertexList[g0, _?(Nand @@ (IntegerQ /@ PropertyValue[{g0, #}, VertexCoordinates]) &)]]
```

[image]

Make the edges straight lines:

```
torusGraph[{4, 5}, {2, 3}, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Used curved edges to indicate periodic boundaries:

```
SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction ->
  (If[ManhattanDistance @@ #[[{1, -1}]] > 1, 
     GraphElementData["CurvedArc"][##], 
     GraphElementData["Line"][##]] &)]
```

[image]

Use a custom `EdgeShapeFunction` to indicate periodic boundaries:

```
ClearAll[periodicEdges, eSF]
periodicEdges[off_: 50] := Module[{vc = Sort[#[[{1, -1}]]], 
    offset = off Unitize[Subtract @@ Sort[#[[{1, -1}]]]]}, 
   {Arrowheads[{{.03, .75}}], 
    Arrow[{vc[[1]], Offset[- offset, vc[[1]]]}], 
    Arrow[{vc[[2]], Offset[ offset, vc[[2]]]}]}] &

eSF = If[ManhattanDistance @@ #[[{1, -1}]] > 1, periodicEdges[][#], 
    GraphElementData["Line"][##]] &;

torusGraph[{4, 5}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF]
```

[image]

```
torusGraph[{4, 5}, {2, 3}, EdgeShapeFunction -> eSF, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Billion thanks @kglr! You have fully answered the problem in its full glory :) Just a naive question, can we also implement, for instance, a hexagonal lattice and then add vertices similarly?

Comment: @Shamina, my pleasure. `ResourceFunction[TorusGraph]` was easy to modify to get the desired result. If you have a similar function that generates a hexagonal lattice it may be possible to modify it in a similar way.

Comment: @Shamina You can use [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html) to generate a periodic triangular lattice (which gives you a hexagonal neighborhood). I suppose that then would be easy to apply the method by kglr.

Comment: If you want to simply add vertices as subdivisions along the hexagonal lattice vectors, then note that's the same as the rectangular lattice topology @kglr showed above - and then use the hexagonal lattice vectors to transform `VertexCoordinates`.

Comment: @Shamina, if you are content with the solutions, it is a good practice to accept them as "answered" if you haven't already

Answer (score 10):

### Edit 03

Here's a function to wrap all this up and answer the latest questions in the comments.
Some utility functions:

```
makePeriodicLattice2D[pts_, {sizeH_, sizeV_}] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[pts]}, 
  Transpose[
   MapThread[
    Mod[#1, #2, -#2/2] &, {Transpose[pts, 
      RotateLeft[Range[d]]], {sizeH, sizeV}}], 
   RotateRight[Range[d]]]]
makePeriodicCartesian2D[pts_, {sizeH_, sizeV_}, latticeVectors_] := 
 With[{inv = Inverse[latticeVectors]}, 
  makePeriodicLattice2D[pts . inv, {sizeH, sizeV}] . latticeVectors]

periodicDistanceLatticePair[{x1_, x2_}, {sizeH_, sizeV_}] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x1]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicLattice2D[
    Outer[Subtract, x1, x2, 1], {sizeH, sizeV}], {d}]]
periodicDistanceCartesianPair[{x1_, x2_}, {sizeH_, sizeV_}, 
  latticeVectors_] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x1]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicCartesian2D[Outer[Subtract, x1, x2, 1], {sizeH, sizeV},
     latticeVectors], {d}]]

linked[mat_?MatrixQ, r_?Positive] := 
 Map[Boole[0 < # <= r] &, mat, {2}]
```

Main function:

```
periodicLatticeGraph[latticeVecs_, 
  motif_, {horizontalExtent_, verticalExtent_}, bondsMatrix_] := 
 Block[{latt, pdm, gg},
  latt = Tuples[{Range[-horizontalExtent, horizontalExtent - 1], 
     Range[-verticalExtent, verticalExtent - 1]}];
  latt = # . latticeVecs & /@ Outer[Plus, motif, latt, 1];
  
  pdm = ArrayFlatten[
    MapThread[
     linked[periodicDistanceCartesianPair[#1, 
        2 {horizontalExtent, verticalExtent}, 
        latticeVecs], #2] &, {Partition[Tuples[latt, 2], 
       Length[motif]], bondsMatrix}, 2]]; 
  gg = AdjacencyGraph[pdm, VertexCoordinates -> Join @@ latt, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedArc"]]
```

and the rectangular example again with different horizontal/vertical extents and a curved `EdgeShapeFunction` to illustrate it's indeed periodic:

```
periodicLatticeGraph[
 {{1, 0}, {0, 3/4}},
 {{0, 0}, {1/3, 0}, {2/3, 0}},
 {4, 2},
 ReplacePart[ConstantArray[1/2, {3, 3}], {1, 1} -> 3/4]]
```

[image]

A hexagonal lattice with (2,1) subdivisions along the lattice vectors

```
periodicLatticeGraph[{{1/2,-Sqrt[3]/2},{1/2,Sqrt[3]/2}},N[{{0,0},{0,1/2},{1/3,0},{2/3,0}}],{3,3},ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0.1,{4,4}],{{1,2},{2,1},{1,3},{3,1},{1,4},{4,1},{3,4},{4,3}}->0.5]]
```

[image]

and just for fun, a graphene (honeycomb) lattice:

```
periodicLatticeGraph[{{1/2,-Sqrt[3]/2},{1/2,Sqrt[3]/2}},N[{{0,0},{1/3,2/3}}],{3,3},ReplacePart[ConstantArray[1/Sqrt[2],{2,2}],{1,1}->0.1]]
```

[image]

### Edit 02

Perhaps what you're looking for can be achieved using a lattice motif and a block periodic distance matrix (think of it like making a crystal lattice with different types of atoms and then specifying different 'bond lengths'). Here's an example:

First, let's change the `periodicDistance` functions to accept two sets of lattice points:

```
periodicDistanceLatticePair[{x1_, x2_}, size_] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x1]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicLattice[Outer[Subtract, x1, x2, 1], size], {d}]]
periodicDistanceCartesianPair[{x1_, x2_}, size_, latticeVectors_] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x1]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicCartesian[Outer[Subtract, x1, x2, 1], size, 
    latticeVectors], {d}]]
```

make a lattice using the motif `((0,0),(1/2,0))`

```
latticeVectors["rect"]=latticeConstant{{1,0},{0,3/4}};
motif["rect"]={{0,0},{1/2,0}};
lattice["rect"]=Tuples[Range[-latticeRadius,latticeRadius-1],2];
lattice["rect"]=#.latticeVectors["rect"]&/@Outer[Plus,motif["rect"],lattice["rect"],1];
```

and then compute the periodic distance matrix block-wise, i.e. (top-left, A-A, bond-length `3/4 a`), (top-right, A-B, bond-length `1/2 a`), (bottom-left, B-A, bond-length `1/2 a`), (bottom-right, B-B, bond-length `1/2 a`), where A,B denote the different motif atoms and `a` is the lattice constant:

```
pdm["rect"]=ArrayFlatten[MapThread[linked[periodicDistanceCartesianPair[#1,2 latticeRadius,latticeVectors["rect"]],#2]&,{Partition[Tuples[lattice["rect"],2],2],latticeConstant{{3/4,1/2},{1/2,1/2}}},2]];
gg["rect"]=AdjacencyGraph[pdm["rect"],VertexCoordinates->Join@@lattice["rect"]];
VertexDegree[gg["rect"]]//Tally
HighlightGraph[gg["rect"],NeighborhoodGraph[gg["rect"],Position[Join@@lattice["rect"],{1/2,0}][[1,1]]]]
```

`{{4, 36}, {2, 36}}`
[image]

### Edit 01

In response to a comment about identifying nearest-neighbors not based on cartesian distance, I realized it's actually much simpler to construct the adjacency graph in the lattice domain.

E.g. for a rectangular lattice:

```
latticeVectors["rect"]=latticeConstant{{1,0},{0,1/4}};
lattice["rect"]=Tuples[Range[-latticeRadius,latticeRadius-1],2].latticeVectors["rect"];
pdm["rect"]=periodicDistanceLattice[lattice["rect"].Inverse[latticeVectors["rect"]],2 latticeRadius];
gg["rect"]=AdjacencyGraph[linked[pdm["rect"],1],VertexCoordinates->lattice["rect"]];
VertexDegree[gg["rect"]]//Tally
HighlightGraph[gg["rect"],NeighborhoodGraph[gg["rect"],Position[lattice["rect"],{2,0}][[1,1]]]]
```

`{{4,36}}`
[image]

### Original Post

Not sure I understood your question correctly, especially the part about adding vertices along edges to augment the lattice.

However, the following builds arbitrary periodic lattice graphs in n dimensions (well, at-least 2 and 3). Tested with primitive unit cells (i.e. one atom per unit-cell), but should be easy to extend to a lattice with a motif.

The idea is to generate a lattice of points, and then compute the adjacency matrix of the graph using a periodic distance matrix. I suspect there's many ways to do this, here I just using Mod in the regular lattice domain and then transform back to the cartesian domain.

```
makePeriodicLattice[pts_, size_] := Mod[pts, size, -size/2 ]
makePeriodicCartesian[pts_, size_, latticeVectors_] := 
 With[{inv = Inverse[latticeVectors]},
  Mod[pts . inv, size, -size/2 ] . latticeVectors]

periodicDistanceLattice[x_, size_] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicLattice[Outer[Subtract, x, x, 1], size], {d}]]
periodicDistanceCartesian[x_, size_, latticeVectors_] := 
 With[{d = ArrayDepth[x]}, 
  Map[Norm, 
   makePeriodicCartesian[Outer[Subtract, x, x, 1], size, 
    latticeVectors], {d}]]
```

Finally, let's define some utility functions and constants to make the adjacency graph:

```
linked[mat_?MatrixQ, r_?Positive] := Map[Boole[0 < # <= r] &, mat, {2}]
latticeRadius = 3;
latticeConstant = 1;
```

### Examples

#### Hexagonal Lattice (2D)

```
latticeVectors["hexagonal"]=latticeConstant{{1/2,-Sqrt[3]/2},{1/2,Sqrt[3]/2}};
lattice["hexagonal"]=Tuples[Range[-latticeRadius,latticeRadius-1],2].latticeVectors["hexagonal"];
pdm["hexagonal"]=periodicDistanceCartesian[lattice["hexagonal"],2 latticeRadius,latticeVectors["hexagonal"]];
gg["hexagonal"]=AdjacencyGraph[linked[pdm["hexagonal"],latticeConstant],VertexCoordinates->lattice["hexagonal"]];
VertexDegree[gg["hexagonal"]]//Tally
HighlightGraph[gg["hexagonal"],NeighborhoodGraph[gg["hexagonal"],Position[lattice["hexagonal"],{0,0}][[1,1]]]]
```

`(*{{6,36}}*)`

[image]

#### Square Lattice (2D)

```
latticeVectors["square"]=latticeConstant{{1,0},{0,1}};
lattice["square"]=Tuples[Range[-latticeRadius,latticeRadius-1],2].latticeVectors["square"];
pdm["square"]=periodicDistanceCartesian[lattice["square"],2 latticeRadius,latticeVectors["square"]];
gg["square"]=AdjacencyGraph[linked[pdm["square"],latticeConstant],VertexCoordinates->lattice["square"]];
VertexDegree[gg["square"]]//Tally
HighlightGraph[gg["square"],NeighborhoodGraph[gg["square"],Position[lattice["square"],{0,0}][[1,1]]]]
```

`(*{{4,36}}*)`

[image]

#### Face-Centered Cubic Lattice (3D)

```
latticeVectors["FCC"]=latticeConstant{{0,1/2,1/2},{1/2,0,1/2},{1/2,1/2,0}};
lattice["FCC"]=Tuples[Range[-latticeRadius,latticeRadius-1],3].latticeVectors["FCC"];
pdm["FCC"]=periodicDistanceCartesian[lattice["FCC"],2 latticeRadius,latticeVectors["FCC"]];
gg["FCC"]=AdjacencyGraph[linked[pdm["FCC"],latticeConstant/Sqrt[2]],VertexCoordinates->lattice["FCC"]];
VertexDegree[gg["FCC"]]//Tally
HighlightGraph[gg["FCC"],NeighborhoodGraph[gg["FCC"],Position[lattice["FCC"],{0,0,0}][[1,1]]]]
```

`(*{{12,216}}*)`

[image]

Comment: If I understand the OP, you're close, but you still have vertex spacing of $1$ in each direction.  The OP wants (for example) $5$ vertices linked horizontally for each $1$ link vertically.... *not* square.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As already mentioned by @DavidG.Stork, it is quite close. But I am interested in the case, when the vertex spacing is not 1 in each direction, as already pointed above.  That is, can we add a vertex with a different coordination number? For instance, in your square lattice, to add a vertex between adjacent vertices? (Don’t hesitate to see the main question)

Comment: Your edit looks excellent! Is there a way to change the number of added vertices in the horizontal section? For e.g., now you have one extra, can we have two, three, four, etc. Also can we have a periodic boundary condition for the `gg["rect"]`? (in edit 3). Many thanks!!

Comment: Also, is there a way to control the size of the lattice?

Comment: @Shamina have a look at the new edit - The number of in-between vertices (or any other arrangement of vertices really) is controlled by the `motif` argument above. This is expecting a list of (u,v) lattice coordinates for each vertex, whereby they'll get dotted with the lattice vectors (a,b) to give (x,y) = (u,v).(a,b). In your case we can use something as simple as `Thread[{Most[Subdivide[3]], 0}]` for two subdivisions.